# Commands like push, pull from git-bash on Windows freezes indefinitely

Tags: git-bash

Commands like `git pull`, `git push`, `git pull --rebase origin master`, etc. freeze indefinitely on git-bash.

However, the same operations work fine from Github desktop app.

OS: Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager) used by git-bash, git-windows, etc. (if configured during git install) needs to be authenticated with Github to run these commands.

Trying the commands from git-windows prompted for authentication options (web browser/personal token). On successful authentication, commands started running fine from git-windows and git-bash as well.

Issue raised for git-bash: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3284